# azure data factory- how to copy data from a list of tables into the another list of table?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I want to copy data from a list of tables from the source into the  target tables
In source i have below 3 tables

```
test_cus1
test_cust2
test_cust3
```

into the following target tables

```
tar_cus1
tar_cus2
tar_cust3
```

so  i have to make sure that data from test_cus1 are copying into the tar_cus1 table and not into tar_cus2 table.
the source and target are same azure sql db.

i have done following configuration

```
i created parameters for above source and target table
1. i used foreach activity and within used copy activity-
2. inside copy activity, i configured the source table - as a iteration item from the source with a script 
select * from the source_parameter_item
3. inside the sink- used table as item from the target parameter
```

but the pipeline fails with a bad request.

#Expected:

```
foreach --> iterate over the source table,

source-select * from iterateble item,

sink -- how to insert into the respective target table ?
```

so what is the right approach to achieve that?

Comment: Looks like you have the right approach. Please post the error details and a screenshot\json of your pipeline.

Comment: Please edit to provide a [mcve] - right now it's a wide open question, based on just a set of requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Create manual table in sql database with source and sink table using below code:

```
create  table lookuptable(source_table varchar(20), target_table varchar(20))
insert  into lookuptable(source_table,target_table)values('test_cus1','tar_cus1'),('test_cus2','tar_cus2'),('test_cus3','tar_cus3')
select  *  from lookuptable
```

[image]

Create a sql dataset with above table. Add Lookup activity with  above dataset you will get the result as shown below:

[image]

After the successful lookup, connect for each item and add  `@activity('Lookup1').output.value`  as dynamic content in the item tab. Go to the activities of foreach and select the copy activity, create linked service and create dataset with  `tableName`  parameters with the values below:

**Source:**

```
tableName: @item().source_table
```

**Source:**

```
tableName: @item().target_table
```

Use the parameters above as the directory of the table in copy activity source and sink datasets as mentioned below:

```
Table: dbo.@dataset.tableName
```

Debug the pipeline; it will run successfully as shown below:

[image]

The target table data is copied successfully to the target tables. Make sure the columns of source and target table are same. For more information, you can refer to the pipeline JSON as mentioned below:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                        "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                        "partitionOption": "None"
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "sourcedb",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                                    "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                                    "partitionOption": "None"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                                    "writeBehavior": "insert",
                                    "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "sourcedb1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "tableNmae": {
                                            "value": "@item().source_table",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "sourcedb1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "tableNmae": {
                                            "value": "@item().target_table",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Bhavani.. Thanks for your response,,, However i have data set created already that point to the sql db and i can use the same for source and sink. I have list of tables for source and target which i paramterized, only the difference is the both table names are different in the same DB. in that case should i need to use the lookup since we already have table name list parameterized ?

Comment: Are you using same db as source and sink?

Comment: Yes @Bhavani. As mentioned, i have list of tables for source and sink parameterized in the pipeline

Comment: Then create two separate sql datasets for source and sink and parametrize the tables according to your requirement in source and sink.

Comment: As mentioned, dataset for both are same which point to the same DB. the challenge is in the sink , i am not sure how to specify the list of target table names from the parameter. when i configured so, its failing
foreach --> iterate over the source table,
      source-select * from iterateble item,
      sink -- how to insert into the respective target table ?
hope you understood my challenge

Comment: @Hari I have updated the answer according to your requirement, please check it.

Comment: you have mentioned two time source, is that expected?

Comment: Yes, it is excepted one source is to take that manual table and one is for take the source tables.

Comment: Please refrain from lengthy discussion in comments - that's not what comments are for. Also, not the place to be posting updated requirements - that belongs *in the question*, along with all relevant details around the attempt to solve the problem, specific issues, etc. Note that the question is off-topic (it's just a set of requirements and a request for help). There is no need to build a custom solution - this is not how Stack Overflow works. Tl;dr you haven't *answered* any specific question - you built a custom solution.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Understand what you meant by here.. But in some  exceptional case  we cannot post the technical diagram. Here the pipeline diagram cannot be captured from a secure env and we may not prefer to replicate the same in a personal account as it charge more. however the above solution address many technical challenges. we still trust stackoverflow do much better than what chatgpt does. Thanks